# @Input in amgulare

Tags: html, angular

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
src/app/products/components/all-products/all-products.component.html:6:16 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'app-select'.

1. If 'app-select' is an Angular component with 'data' input, verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-select' is a Web Component, add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

```
    6    <app-select [data]="categories"></app-select>
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/products/components/all-products/all-products.component.ts:6:16
        6   templateUrl: './all-products.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component AllProductsComponent.
    ERROR
    src/app/shared/components/select/select.component.ts:10:4 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Input'. Did you mean 'oninput'?
    
    10   @Input() title:string = ""
          ~~~~~
    
      node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:27386:13
        27386 declare var oninput: ((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                          ~~~~~~~
        'oninput' is declared here.
    ERROR
    src/app/shared/components/select/select.component.ts:11:4 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Input'. Did you mean 'oninput'?
    
    11   @Input() data:any[]=[]
          ~~~~~
    
      node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:27386:13
        27386 declare var oninput: ((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null;
                          ~~~~~~~
        'oninput' is declared here.
```

I want to send the data.

Comment: did you register `app-select` in `app-module` or the respective `module` file? Also, did you import `Input`? Is the line 11 defined in `app-select` component? Please add a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: input -> @Input

Answer (score 2):

Did you forgot to import it from the '@angular/core' library.

In your select.component.ts file, at the top, add the following import statement:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

The Top of your file should properly look like this.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent {
  @Input() title: string = "";
  @Input() data: any[] = [];
}
```

Now, in your AllProductsComponent, you should be able to pass the 'categories' variable to your 'app-select' component like this code.

```
<app-select [data]="categories"></app-select>
```

Make sure that the SelectComponent is declared in your module typescript file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // other stuff
    SelectComponent
  ],
  // more properties
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Cause of minimum information to your question (missing code), this is just a general try to help.
Please post also the code of your problem, if you need a better (more detailled) answer.